# What does it mean to take a derivative with respect to $\hbar$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

Problem 6.32 of Griffiths *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, 2ed* is

[image]

In part (b), we take a derivative with respect to $\hbar$. Since $\hbar$ is a constant, what does it mean to take a derivative with respect to it?

(The problem above is just an example; I'm not interested in the problem itself.)

Comment: It is a constant in the real world. Algebraically, we can write out all of our expressions (for probabilities, etc.) as being functions of $\hbar$. We can then take as many derivatives w.r.t. $\hbar$ as we want. The reason doing this kind of manipulation is interesting is precisely what the problem is trying to teach. For the problem at hand, you can deduce $\langle T \rangle$ from this.

Comment: ↑, or put it another way, $\hbar$ can be thought of as a formal variable, that is, $\frac{\partial}{\partial\hbar} \mathrm e^{-ipx/\hbar}=\frac{ipx}{\hbar^2}\mathrm e^{-ipx/\hbar}$